# Running c++ application using JNI functions in debug build causes segmentation fault

Tags: java, c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, java-native-interface

I've got a c++ application that uses jni to get access to java functions.
As long as I build my application in **release** everything is fine and works. But when I build the application in **debug**, the application crashes as soon as it calls the jni code.

I'm using QTCreator under Ubuntu 14.04 x64 with gcc 4.8.2 and java 1.7.0_75

Example Methode:

```
void JNICommunicator::queryJNI_deleteIndividual(std::string path, std::string individualName){
    if(jvmStatus != JNI_ERR){

        jclass cls = env->FindClass("de/myclasspacked/MyClass"); //when getting to this point, the application crashes

        if(env->ExceptionOccurred()){
            env->ExceptionDescribe();

        }

        if(cls != 0){
            jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "()V");
            jobject object = env->NewObject(cls, constructor);

            jmethodID mAC = env->GetMethodID(cls, "deleteIndividual", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");

            if(mAC != 0){

                jstring path = env->NewStringUTF(owlPath.c_str());
                jstring individualNameTemp = env->NewStringUTF(individualName.c_str());
                jobject jAdd = env->CallObjectMethod(object, mAC, path, individualNameTemp);

                if(env->ExceptionOccurred()){
                    env->ExceptionDescribe();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any ideas why it crashes or how I can get the application working under debug? Its hard do develop an application without the ability to use debug functions.

Thanks
Best Regards

I get my env from here. This is how I initiate my JVM:

```
void initJVM(){
std::string dPath = "-Djava.class.path=/svn/owl/OWLApiExample/bin";
char *cstr = new char[dPath .length()+1];
strcpy(cstr, dPath .c_str());

options[0].optionString = cstr;
options[1].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=/svn/owl/OWLApiExample/lib";
options[2].optionString = "-verbose:jni";

vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vm_args);
jvmStatus = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

if(jvmStatus != JNI_ERR){
    //log
}else{

    jsize nVMs;
    jvmStatus = JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(NULL, 0, &nVMs);      // 1. just get the required array length
    jvmStatus = JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(&jvm, nVMs, &nVMs);   // 2. get the data

    jvmStatus = jvm->GetEnv((void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    if (jvmStatus == JNI_EDETACHED){

        if (jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void **) &env, NULL) != 0) {
            //log
        }else{

    }else if (jvmStatus == JNI_EVERSION) {
        //log
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting your `env` value from?

Comment: Hey Andrew, I updated my post.